# Adding non-button control to TinyMCE editor 4.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE editor (version 4.0.1). I've been trying to add a checkbox to the editor toolbar but can't figure out how to do it.

For normal buttons, I've used the `addButton` function. But I'm stuck on how to add other TinyMCE UI types such as a checkbox to the toolbar.

The documentation for the `addButton` function says it:

> Adds a button that later gets created by the ControlManager. This is a shorter and easier method of adding buttons without the need to deal with the ControlManager directly. But it's also less powerfull if you need more control use the ControlManagers factory methods instead.

I tried to the `ControlManager` class, but it seems only appear in the TinyMCE 3.x API.

One solution would be to use the UI Factory create method and render the UI item directly to the HTML of the TinyMCE editor, but this seems a little clumsy:

```
tinyMCE.ui.Factory.create({
  type: 'checkbox',
  checked: true,
  text: 'My checkbox'
}).renderTo($('#mce_92-body')[0]);
```

Can anyone think of a better approach?

See http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.ui.Checkbox
and http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton

Comment: How do you programmatically retrieve the name of your #mce_92-body element?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your tinymce init method:

```
setup : function(ed) {
                    ed.addButton('check', {
                        type:'checkbox',
                        text: 'some descriptive label',
                    });
                },
```